# No Module Named Aiofiles (On Zaphosting Server)

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, bots

I wanna host my Discord Bot on a Server.
Now I have uploaded my files of the bot and when I start it up, it says NoModuleFounderror: no module named aiofiles.
The Server is being hosted on Zaphosting. How do I install the packages/modules? I cannot find anything in the internet, so I hope this will get to solve my error.

Comment: Is `pip install` a thing you can do?

Comment: Well, I did that in the console, but it didn’t do anything.